# is there any way to find long running blocks of procedure/packages in oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, sql-tuning

is there any way to find long running blocks of procedure/packages in oracle database?
I have a requirement to tune oracle procedures .
I donot know which sql in the query is taking long time and there are around 30+ sql's being called .
Is there any way to find out long running sql of the package/procedure by executing procedure ?

Comment: look at V$SESSION_LONGOPS and v$sqlarea views

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a hierarchical profiler in the database.  Enable it, run your PL/SQL package or procedure, turn off the profiler and query the DBMSHP_* tables.  They will tell you how much time was spent in each call and in each SQL statement on each line.  It is the "go to" utility for tuning PL/SQL.

You can read about in the 12c documention here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_hprof.htm#ARPLS146

Answer (score 1):

There are several profilers and scripts to look at performance in the DB and specifically stored procedures. An older but still good read is here, http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_ioug_proc.htm

Depending on your skillset running scripts and using more advanced profilers, a rudamentary option would be to use the DBA function of Oracle's SQL Developer GUI interface.  Basically connect to the server in question where you run the stored procedures and then watch the CPU performance and I/O using the statistics tab which can also be output to a log.  This is basically resource manager information.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbp/use-sql-developer-monitor-database-performance-ee.html#GUID-83539ADE-7D5A-49B7-80DA-AE1AA33B935A

You can also use SQL Developer to Debug your procedures as needed,
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/appdev.41/e55591/sql-developer-concepts-usage.htm#f1_idecodeeditor_html